# Analytical Trignometry

Tags: angle, constants

I have two questions :
A)Can someone answer this and explain how he/she answered.

α tan(α+π)=

1. −tanα
2. tanα
3. ctgα
4. None of the above

B) why is cos100 = -cos80

thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

note that $$\tan(\alpha+\pi)=\tan(\alpha)$$ since $\pi$ is the period
further we have $$\cos(100^{\circ})=\cos(180^{\circ}-80^{\circ})=-\cos(80^{\circ})$$

Answer (score 0):

For part $b$, by using the identity

$$\cos(A-B)=\cos(A)\cos(B)+\sin(A)\sin(B)$$
$$\cos(100^\circ)=\cos(180^\circ-80^\circ)=\cos(180^\circ)\cos(80^\circ)+\sin(180^\circ)\sin(80^\circ)$$
$$\implies \cos(100^\circ)=-\cos(80^\circ)$$

Because $\cos(180^\circ)=-1$ and $\sin(180^\circ)=0$